# Oil and Gas Fields In Iraq?

Tags: data, oil-gas, iraq

I have scoured all the sources I thought might have these features in vector format but all I've found are maps upon maps. [Here's](http://legacy.lib.utexas.edu/maps/middle_east_and_asia/iraq_oil_2003.jpg) or [here](https://wiki.aapg.org/File:M106Ch12Fig01.jpg) examples of what I'm looking for; I've tracked down the original sources but no digital versions. The data download link [here](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1997/ofr-97-470/OF97-470B/) is broken and I've gone through every snapshot on Wayback Machine, no luck. Anyone familiar with other possible sources for this data? It's super frustrating to see so [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=oil%20and%20gas%20fields%20iraq%20KML&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi785O-85HgAhVlm-AKHUyvAao4ChD8BQgOKAE&biw=1522&bih=635) maps depicting these fields but on data access.

Comment: Field locations are extremely expensive to acquire, and often come with non-distribution license constraints. I suspect you will continue to be frustrated if you aren't prepared to part with US$100K to obtain this data.

Answer (score 1):

One version available [here](https://services5.arcgis.com/KKQgnx5lQS5naLaq/arcgis/rest/services/HC_Field/FeatureServer) on ArcGIS Online but the only option I've found, not as extensive as those depicted in the other maps above.